# Escape utf8 using regex

Tags: java, regex, utf-8

I did a data processing job and unescaped data by mistake. It replaced all utf-8 like `\x0a\xfa to x0axfa`
I want to write a regex to place those `\` back before x. I tried this:

```
`regex:((\([\x00-\x7F]\)|\w){2})+`
replace with: \\$1
```

However, it replaces everything before last 2 characters with `\`. What's the correct way to solve this problem. (I have to do regex replace, cannot do data processing again. Its huge.)

> Input: blah blah x0ax0fx12...
>
> Desired Output: blah blah \x0a\x0f\x12...

Comment: Now, it is  next to impossible to help. `x[a-fA-F0-9]{2}` is what you may try and replace with `\\$0` but there is no guarantee you won't replace more than you need.

Comment: You’re going to have a hard time writing a regex that is smart enough to leave the words like “exact” and “axed” alone.

Answer (score 1):

Use a look behind to prevent escaping already escaped stuff, and a look ahead to find the insertion point for the slash:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?<!\\\\)(?=x[a-z0-9]{2,})", "\\\\");
```

The quadruple backslash is needed for a literal backslash in a Java regex; escaped once for the regex, then each one again for the string literal.

Answer (score 0):

In a case like this, I would use an expression like `(x[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})+` to identify the chunk of UTF-8 data without backslashes on each line.

From there, you can use Java's string.split("x") to make an array of strings representing the bytes without the "x".  If `regexMatch` is a string containing the match from your expression like "x0ax0fx12", then you could do something like this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String inputText = "blah blah x0ax0fx12 blah blah";
        String regexMatch = "";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(x[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})+");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputText);                
        if (matcher.find()) {
            regexMatch = matcher.group(0);
        }                
        String replacedOutput = "";
        for (String splitStr : regexMatch.split("x")) {            
            if (!splitStr.equals("")) {                
                replacedOutput += "\\x" + splitStr;
            }            
        }        
      System.out.println(replacedOutput); 
   }
}
```

This should output "\x0a\x0f\x12" and you should be able to substitute it back into the line that matched in your file at the point where the matcher found it.